# Program doesn't return 0, "this hasn't been built yet" pops up infinitely

Tags: c, codeblocks

I just downloaded CodeBlocks and made my first console application, and I have mingw installed but I tried running the default code and the popup "it seems this project has not been built yet. do you want to build it now?" keeps popping up endlessly.

If I click no, the program does run, but it doesn't print the text and it doesn't return 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, it's supposed to return 0, but it's returning 4258096 (0x40F930).

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Giraffe.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Giraffe.exe obj\Debug\main.o' in 'C:\Users\soph1\Desktop\Giraffe' failed.
```

what does the error mean?

edit: it's still giving me that error and doing the same thing after trying to change the compiler.

I'm just going to use an online c compiler. It seems to be working perfectly so... I guess codeblocks and every other dang IDE I tried to use is just stupid.

Comment: This isn't enough information.

Comment: I think you should click "yes" and build the code.

Comment: I did click yes, but it just keeps popping up until I click no or cancel.

Comment: There should be a build console somewhere. Probably it is showing some errors.

Comment: Oh. Yeah there's an error.
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Giraffe.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Giraffe.exe obj\Debug\main.o' in 'C:\Users\soph1\Desktop\Giraffe' failed.

Comment: `mingw32-g++.exe` is a C compiler? Or a C++ compiler? I believe it doesn't matter greatly for this issue, but if you're writing C code: use a C compiler!

Comment: @pmg: mingw32-g++.exe is a C++ compiler. The C compiler of MinGW should be mingw32-gcc.exe.

Comment: `Execution of mingw32-g++.exe failed` means that Code::Blocks can't find the compiler. Check the settings in Settings->Compiler->toolchain executables to see if the path are set and valid. Check if you can run the command from a command line.

Comment: It probably means that either your Code::Blocks or the compiler is mis-configured, or somehow not installed correctly.

Comment: There's no source file listed in the compile command. Have you made sure to add the source files?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go ahead is to download the full installer of CodeBlocks, the one which includes the compiler too (MinGW).

After install, load the project again. Find the option "Build and run" and use that. Everything will be OK.

Occasionally, if you feel that you run old code, you can choose the "Rebuild all" option.

---

Note: the "(Re)Build" part is the one which transforms the source code into an executable something. Without this, the computer will not be able to execute your program.

Comment: It is on the download page of Codeblocks.

Comment: To have the installer with MinGW included, for Windows, choose the file name ending in "mingw-setup.exe" from either download site provided.

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked, I just reinstalled the version that comes with mingw (i think). I would upvote but I'm not allowed to so thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that it works. Maybe you can choose this as the correct answer then :)